# Python: Pandas Merge creates more rows than there are datapoints?

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have trouble with merging 2 DataFrame, because the result I get seems to me unreasonable.

I have a DataFrame A, which has the size: 39400 Rows and 52 Columns
Then there is DataFrame B with 43940 Rows and 283 Columns

Now I want to merge these 2 based on the column "Filename"

```
merged = A.merge(B, on = "Filename", how = "left")
```

But the DataFrame merged now contains 39502 Rows and 334 columns. I get the same result if I use how = "left", "right", "inner" or "outter"

But it does not make sense that my merged DataFrame has 102 rows more than DataFrame A.

What am I missing?

Comment: Do you have duplicate values in the `filename` column in either frame?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably due to duplicates. Just drop them before merging.

```
A = A.drop_duplicates(subset=['Filename'])
B = B.drop_duplicates(subset=['Filename'])
```